# Branch Referral Credits not being applied

Tags: branch.io

I'm implementing a Branch referral program into my application, but cannot get the rewards to apply correctly. The rule is straightforward and says:

```
Referring users get 7 default credits the first time users they've referred trigger the event registered
```

I'm running in `debug` mode and make sure to sign in using a brand new developer ID each time. I also follow the directions in [**Simulate an Install**](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#simulate-an-install).

I use the legacy `userCompletedAction` method, as specified [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/referrals/#guide). I call this after setting the identity, as so:

```
[[Branch getInstance] setIdentity:@"..." withCallback:^(...) {
    [[Branch getInstance] userCompletedAction:@"registered"];
    ...
}];
```

The referral seems to work since both `+is_first_session` and `+clicked_branch_link` are true, and `$identity_id` matches that of the referring user.

I can confirm that I see the event happen in the **Event** section of the **LiveView** tab of the Branch Dashboard (see screenshot below).

[image: Branch Dashboard Screenshot]

I do however not see anything in the "Credits" section a few tabs over, and can confirm that the credits were not applied to the referring user's account.

I have attempted to modify my rule to apply **every time** referred user's trigger the event `registered` to rule out any bugs related to using the same device, but it made no difference. I have created the rule in the test environment as well.

Any idea what's going wrong, why this is not working?

Comment: Hey, @Aleksander i am using React native and i have the exact same issue. I am primarily developing it for iOS. Can you please help me out with a solution? Is it resovled? How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Same issue. @YashKalwani, any luck?

Comment: @njho unfortunately I have not been able to fully figure this out yet, how Branch works is still a mystery to me - the behavior is very inconsistent and docs are lacking at best. Will update this question if I have anything more concrete.

Comment: @YashKalwani please see above comment

Comment: @Aleksander I agree. There documentation has been pretty poor (at least for React Native). It'd be best if they had a walkthrough for common scenarios (as per what seems common now). After talking with Branch, it seems like you may need unique devices to simulate (and therefore a simulatore unsuitable)... Something that isn't explicitely listed in their documentation, nor were they aware of... I had a couple of referrals squeeze through when I started using unique devices.